# Can a QoS Guaranteed pod be evicted by a higher priority pod?

Tags: kubernetes

Considering the scenario where all of the nodes are fully utilized and there is a user's pod in the scheduler queue that has a higher priority, and there are no more Best Effort and Burstable pods left, only Guaranteed with lower priority, then can that Guaranteed pod be evicted to make space for the higher priority one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Interactions between Pod priority and quality of service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#interactions-of-pod-priority-and-qos)

> The scheduler's preemption logic does not consider QoS when choosing preemption targets. Preemption considers Pod priority and attempts to choose a set of targets with the lowest priority.

So a Pod with QoS "Guaranteed" may be evicted if a higher priority Pod gets scheduled.

Comment: So to summarise, a lower priority Guaranteed pod can be evicted to make room for a higher priority pod during preemption (when scheduling). But a lower priority Guaranteed pod will not be evicted before a higher priority pod but with a lower QoS class during out-of-resources eviction. Is this statement correct @Jonas?

Comment: yes, that sounds correct based on the info in the documentation.